# AWS S3 endpoint used on Boto3 come from?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access to S3 using boto3 or simply using cloudberry but in my last company the endpoint_url was always provided by other team, but now I am trying to understand where to generate/origin of that endpoint_url.

Is it generated in a private cloud?

I am trying to generate it on Endpoints tab in VPC section but I cannot access it on CloudBerry. I already have the access keys and secret keys but I am having problem to find out/create the endpoint.

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'STRING',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'STRING',
    endpoint_url= 'http://?????'
)
```

Thanks

Comment: In boto3 you can leave the endpoint_url empty, and it will always connect to AWS. Overriding this variable is only necessary if you have to connect to an onprem installation, an S3-compatible service run by a third-party, or  during testing (e.g. if you're using Moto, Localstack)